# Slow Sidekiq in development only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Running `Sidekiq 6.1.0` on `Rails 5.0.7.2` with Sidekiq concurrency set to 12, `Redis server 4.0.14` and `Redis gem 4.2.1`.

There seems to be some delay (seconds) between queueing/executing jobs that we didn't see with `Rails 4.2.9`. Note, this behavior only occurs in development, production seems to do just fine.

An example worker:

```rb
class SidekiqTestWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options(
    queue: "default",
  )

  def perform
    puts "Hello from Sidekiq!"
  end
end
```

Running `1000.times { SidekiqTestWorker.perform_async }` in a Rails console takes around a second to execute all jobs with `Rails 4.2.9`, but with `Rails 5.0.7.2` it takes several minutes to complete. Worth mentioning that we tried running with the same Sidekiq version (`5.2.8`) with only Rails diffing between the tries with the same result.

A snippet from the Sidekiq worker logs shows the behavior (note the timestamp):

```
16:52:00 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:00 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:00 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:00 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:00 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:00 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:00 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:00 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:00 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:00 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:00 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:01 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:04 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:04 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:04 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:04 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:04 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:04 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:04 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:04 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:04 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:04 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:04 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:05 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:05 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
16:52:05 sidekiq_worker.1 | Hello from Sidekiq!
```

Any ideas what can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Sidekiq 5.0 release notes:

> Sidekiq 5.0 contains a reworked job dispatch and execution core to integrate better with the new Rails 5.0 Executor.

The Rails Executor is single-threaded in development mode so it can hot reload job code changes. Sidekiq can only execute one job at a time.

The only way to fix this is to enable eager loading in `config/environment/development.rb` but that will disable code reloading too.

Comment: Worth mentioning is that you also need to set `cache_classes` to true.